# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authenticate')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am having trouble creating a registration using Express, Node, Mongoose and Passport.js. Installed versions: passport: ^ 0.4.1, passport-local-mongoose ^ 7.0.0, express-session: ^ 1.17.2, express ^ 4.17.3.
It shows me an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authenticate') -> passport.authenticate('local'),

My file server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const { port, mongoURI } = require('./config')
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth')
const path = require('path')
const User = require('./models/Users')
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     
    extended: true
  })); 
app.use(morgan('tiny'))

mongoose
    .connect(mongoURI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB database is connected'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))




app.use(
    session({
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        secret: 'secret',
        store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection : mongoose.connection})
    })
)


passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser())

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())


app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes)

app.use('/api/patients', patientsRoutes)

app.use('/api/employees', employeesRoutes)

// app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello world'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Express is running at port ' + port))
```

My file auth.js:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const { passport } = require('passport')
const User = require('../models/Users')


const router = Router()

router.get('/user', (req, res) => {
    if (req.user){
        res.json({ username: req.user.username })
    } else {
        res.json({ user: null })
    }
})

router.post('/sign-up', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { username, password} = req.body
    try {
        await User.register({username}, password)
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.name == 'UserExistsError'){
            return res.status(400).json({message : 'UserExistsError' })
        }
        return res.status(500).json({message : 'Błąd podczas rejestracji użytkownika!' })
        }
        next()
    }, 
    passport.authenticate('local'), 
    (req, res) => {
        res.json({ user: { username: req.user.username } })
})

module.exports = router
```

My file Users.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose')

const User = new Schema({

})


User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)


module.exports = mongoose.model('user', User)
```

Comment: I changed passport.authenticate to User.authenticate and it works

Answer (score 0):

You were importing passport the wrong way. use `import passport from 'passport'` instead of `import { passport } from 'passport'`. Also, as per your comment, `User.authenticate()` has nothing to do with session which is probably what you originally intended.